# Automatic brightness settings and video card driver

Tags: 12.04, installation, lts

Hello, I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64, I realy need help with automatic brightness settings driver how to?

And second is: no nVidia driver (additional driver) found, if I install the recommended driver, my brightness will be 100% after rebooting with no way to change to other low percentage.

The machine is: Sony Vaio VPC F11 M1 E-H CPU Intel i5 2.40-2.93 , nVidia GT 330m CUDA 1gb, 8gb DDR3

Please help I really want to migrate to Ubuntu Linux but these things are taking me back to wine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you exactly want, but for changing brightness you can probably use xbacklight. After installing it, type this into terminal and it should change brightness to 70%:

```
xbacklight -set 70
```

To have this command ran automatically after logging in, you can put it into .gnomerc file which is located in your home directory (it's a hidden file, use Ctrl-H to show hidden files).